# html form unable to find setter method for attribute name

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I get error `html form unable to find setter method for attribute name` when I add `name` attribute in form action 
like

```
<html:form action="updateBOEMedicalAccept" name="updateBOEMedicalAcceptForm">
```

I need `name` attribute to use it in javascript

like

```
document.updateBOEMedicalAcceptForm.BOE_NO.disabled = true;
```

and `id` attribute is also not working

Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting element by name,

```
document.getElementsByName('BOE_NO').disabled = true;
```

For getting element by id

```
document.getElementsById('idOfBOE_NO').disabled = true;
```